# How can I make rectangle strech across entire grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm building a small WPF application. For the layout in the application, i use a grid with two columns and two rows. I want to have a background rectangle that fills the entire application, and I want the background rectangle to strech so if a user resizes the window, the rectangle streches and always fills the entire window. So inside my grid I have defined a rectangle as follows:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRect" Fill="Stretch">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.485,0.2" Center="0.492,0.526">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3C3C3E" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF84897D"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
</grid>
```

Now, I've tried to set the rectangles Fill to strech, I've set grid.columnspan and grid.rowspan to 2. I've tried to place the rectangle inside a viewbox. Nothing works.

Do anyone know how I can make the rectangle fill my entire window?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Is that fact you are defining the Fill property twice on the Rectangle (once as an attribute and then as child element) just a typo?

Comment: Note that Panels do have a [Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background.aspx) property so, if the ultimate goal is to set a background in the Grid and not perform any other actions with the Rectangle, then you can simply set Grid.Background with the RadialGradientBrush.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, set `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` and `Grid.RowSpan="2"` on your `Rectangle`. You need to do this if you want it to span across the entire Grid.

Second, since you have your `Column/RowDefinition` `Width/Heights` set to `Auto`, nothing will be shown right now because you have no content in those columns/rows to have them size automatically (perhaps you just removed it for the sample?). What you should do is set one of the columns to `Width="*"` and one of the rows to `Height="*"` which basically says: "fill the remainder of horizontal/vertical space with this column/row".

Third, until you put something in the `Grid` you won't see anything because it will have no height. If you just want to make sure your background `Rectangle` is going to display properly, just give the `Grid` a `Height="200"` or something for now.

Comment: Thank you! That was an excellent answer to my question. Now it works exactly as I want it!